# Update query in oracle cancatenating old value

Tags: c#, oracle

While submitting the form, status was 'pending'. After approval I want to change status as below. It is coming but showing as 'pending approved'. I need it to be 'Approved' so before the update query did I want to delete the status of that ID?OR any other way to update query itself?

```
cmd201.CommandText = OracleHelper.FixCommandText(
  "UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET STATUS=@status WHERE ID=@ID");
cmd201.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your code applies a concatenation for `@status` variable before the above code. You don't need to delete nothing or setting `@status` to `null`, before your sql statement. This piece of code shows no problem.